# Modify Woocommerce query to show only products with sale price

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've been using wordpress theme Enfold which includes shortcode to show product slider of Woocommerce products. The filter to edit query is also included:

```
$query = apply_filters('avia_product_slide_query', $query, $params);
```

The default query variable looks something like this:

```
Array(
[post_type] => product
[post_status] => publish
[ignore_sticky_posts] => 1
[paged] => 1
[offset] => 0
[post__not_in] => Array ( )
[posts_per_page] => 9
[orderby] => menu_order title
[order] => ASC
[meta_query] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [key] => _visibility
        [value] => Array (
            [0] => visible
            [1] => catalog
            )
        [compare] => IN
        )
    )
[tax_query] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [taxonomy] => product_cat
        [field] => id
        [terms] => Array (
            [0] => 13
            [1] => 64
            [2] => 65
            [3] => 15
            [4] => 67
            [5] => 66
            [6] => 23
            [7] => 73
            [8] => 75
            [9] => 10
            [10] => 52
            [11] => 53
            [12] => 50
            [13] => 51
            [14] => 12
            [15] => 48
            [16] => 11
            [17] => 44
            [18] => 14
            [19] => 55
            )
        [operator] => IN
        )
    )
)
```

Does anybody know a way to add some filter to this query to show only products which have defined sale price?

Comment: You have woocommerce default shortcode `[sale_products per_page="12"]`, or you can dig in to woocommerce files and see how they queried it. Or alternatively, ask on Enfold support forum ;)

Comment: Sale_products shortcode is not good for me in this case because I need to show products as slider. But thank to this I found what I needed in file class-wc-shortcodes.php in function for this shortcode. Thanks for help.

Comment: No problem, happy to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solve it this way:

```
$query['post__in'] = array_merge( array( 0 ), wc_get_product_ids_on_sale() );
```